# How to create DVD Video with closed captioning?

Tags: captions, closed-captions

How to create DVD Video with closed captioning? (I am having Video and also SRT files) How to do that? any idea/ suggestion?

Guys, I have tested closed Captioning service in my site using youtube API. I need help to add caption offline with the DVD video.

Please share your Ideas and Suggestions...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

http://latentimagedesign.com/ClosedCaptionCreator/create.php

You can load your srt file and export as an adobe XML file. Use adobe CC to convert the XML file to SCC for DVD authoring or embed the closed caption file.